# Configure Slick with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework, azure-sql-database

I have a project that is currently using MySQL that I would like to migrate to SQL Server (running on Azure).  I have tried a lot of combinations of configurations but always get the same generic error message:

```
Cannot connect to database [default]
```

Here is my latest configuration attempt:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:sqlserver://my_host.database.windows.net:1433;database=my_db"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "username"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "password"
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTimeout="10 seconds"
```

I have the `sqljdbc4.jar` in my `lib/` folder.

And have added the following to my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.0.0"

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
```

---

Edit:  I can connect from this machine using a GUI app, so the issue is not with any of the network settings.

Comment: Try to use `slick.dbs.default.db.user = "user@my_host"`, replacing "my_host" with the right value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit: 5/30/2017**

After the release of Slick 3.2 the driver is now in the core suite, these are examples of Configs with 3.2

```
oracle = {
  driver = "slick.jdbc.OracleProfile$"
  db {
    host = ${?ORACLE_HOST}
    port = ${?ORACLE_PORT}
    sid = ${?ORACLE_SID}

    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"${oracle.db.host}":"${oracle.db.port}"/"${oracle.db.sid}
    user = ${?ORACLE_USERNAME}
    password = ${?ORACLE_PASSWORD}
  }
}

sqlserver = {
  driver = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile$"
  db {
    host = ${?SQLSERVER_HOST}
    port = ${?SQLSERVER_PORT}
    databaseName = ${?SQLSERVER_DB_NAME}

    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${sqlserver.db.host}":"${sqlserver.db.port}";databaseName="${sqlserver.db.databaseName}
    user = ${?SQLSERVER_USERNAME}
    password = ${?SQLSERVER_PASSWORD}
  }
}
```

**End Edit**

I only have experience with the oracle config but I believe it is fairly similar. You are missing the critical $ at the end of the default driver. Also you will need to make sure your SBT project recognizes the lib

This first code snippet should be in application.conf or whatever file you are using for your Configuration

```
oracle = {
  driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver$"
  db {
    host = ""
    port = ""
    sid = ""

    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"${oracle.db.host}":"${oracle.db.port}"/"${oracle.db.sid}
    user = ${?USERNAME}
    password = ${?PASSWORD}
    driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  }
}
```

This second section is in my `build.sbt` . I put my oracle driver in the base folder in the `/.lib`, although their may be a better way.

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / ".lib"
```

Finally to make sure the config is loading properly. Slick default seems to misbehave, so hopefully you get a *right* answer, rather than a what works for me answer. However utilizing my config above I can then load that using the last snippet. I found this in an example of a cake implementation and it has worked very well in multiple projects.

```
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("oracle")
  implicit val profile: JdbcProfile = dbConfig.driver
  implicit val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = dbConfig.db
```

This allows you to use the database, the driver for imports and will fail on compile if your configuration is wrong. Hope this helps.

edit : I finished and realized you were working with Azure so make sure that you can fully connect utilizing the same settings from the same machine utilizing a client of your choice. To make sure all firewall and user settings are correct and that the problem truly lies in your code and not in your system configuration.

edit2: Wanted to make sure I didn't give you bad advice since it was an Oracle Config so I set it up against and AWS SQL Server. I utilized the `sqljdbc42.jar` that is given by Microsoft with their jdbc install. Put that in the `.lib` and then I had a configuration like follows. As in the upper example you could instead use Environmental variables but this was just a quick proof of concept. Here is a Microsoft SQL Server Config I have now tested to confirm works.

```
sqlserver = {
  driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver$"
  db {
    driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    host = ""
    port = ""
    databaseName = ""

    url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${sqlserver.db.host}":"${sqlserver.db.port}";databaseName="${sqlserver.db.databaseName}
    user = ""
    password = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `lib` folder of the project?  Or the `lib` folder of your system?

Comment: Question: Where does the `sqlserver = { ... }` variable go under? Is this in the `application.conf` file?

Comment: Yes this goes in the application.conf file.